# MATLAB extract columns of array based on value of another column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a large matrix `A`, which is of size 105000 x 3. I would like to extract the first two columns of the matrix, whenever the third column = `Val`.

I have tried:

```
Test = A(A(:,3) == Val);
```

However, this only extracts the first column. I cannot seem to figure out the syntax to pull out the first and second columns. I know to simply pull out the first two columns it would be `Test = A(:, [1,2])`, so I imagine I need to combine these somehow?

Comment: As a side note, the reason why your code extracts the first column is [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
Test = A(A(:,3) == Val, 1:2);
```

or equivalently

```
Test = A(A(:,3) == Val, [1,2]);
```

The index after the comma dictates the columns, the index before the comma dictates the rows.

Note that equating floating point numbers with `==` can give [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab), you might be better off doing something like

```
tol = 1e-10; % some small tolerance value
Test = A( abs(A(:,3) - Val) < tol, [1,2]);
```

Comment: Great and thanks for the extra tip regarding floating point numbers!